# How to output class/arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, class, netbeans

Ok, so this program allows user to input five adjectives and nouns, which outputs in a paragraph. There is a certain name for this game, usually found in kid's magazines..but the name escapes me right now. Ex. "Mary hopped on the (adjective) horse. and flew over the *_*(noun).

Now I had thought this would all work out nicely since there are no red lines or such. However after I press the "play" button a lovely error pops up.

ex of error...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
```

'5' or any number (n) being the number of nouns I add in the array through the noun TextField. I'm using a GUI by the way, if you're wondering. Sorry if the physical questino makes no sense, I was unsure how to word it.

I've created a class for both noun and adjectives.

```
class noun {
    String noun;

    noun (String _noun) {
       noun = _noun;
    }
}

class adjective {
    String adjective;

    adjective (String _adjective) {
       adjective = _adjective;
    }
}

ArrayList <adjective> small = new ArrayList <adjective>(); //array for adjectives
ArrayList <noun> office = new ArrayList <noun>(); //array for nouns

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //stores info 

        String noun, adjective;

        //Take inputted words
        noun = nounField.getText();
        adjective = adjectiveField.getText();

        //Store values in array ADJECTIVE
        adjective c = new adjective(adjective);
        small.add(c);

        //Store values in array NOUN
        noun d = new noun(noun);
        office.add(d);

    }

private void playButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //play button

        String temp = "";

        //Allows user to view information from array
        for (int x=0; x<=office.size(); x++) {
             temp = temp + " paragraph " + office.get(x).noun + "/n";
        }
        paraTArea.setText(temp); //TextArea where paragraph with nouns etc are outputted
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated! =)

Comment: A few tips: 1) This has nothing to do with arrays, you are working with `Collection` subclasses, and 2) use variable names that make sense to improve code readability.

Comment: FYI, the trade name that I know this game by is "Mad Libs".

Answer (score 4):

the upper bound of the for-loop should either be `x <= office.size() - 1`, or `x < office.size()` because the index is 0-based.

Comment: ahh...I see, wow thanks! That was really a dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can change for loop to either of following:

```
for (int x=0; x<=office.size()-1; x++) //As suggested by mre
```

OR

```
for (int x=0; x<office.size(); x++)
```

Please see if this helps.

Comment: -1 The second for-loop would also cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @HarishKumar You might want to fix it, then.